# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier - Pytorch 1.3.1

Tags: character, pytorch, reshape, identifier

When executing the following method:

```
def flatten(t):
    t = t.reshape(1, −1)
    t = t.squeeze()
    return t
```

Python complains about the second argument.

```
  File "pytorch.py", line 16
t = t.reshape(1, −1)
                  ^       SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

My pytorch version is 1.3.1.
I already tried to remove the space before the argument with no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: As it is now, there doesn't seem to be indentation in your method?

Comment: reddit messed that up after pasting. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character in −1 is not a hyphen. Rather it's the actual minus sign from unicode.
This makes the python interpreter think that −1 is an identifier instead of -1 value.

You might have copied the code from somewhere that has this stylised characters. Just replace `−` with `-`

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot.